# My restfull api is not responsing data on online server but working in local server

Tags: php, rest, api

My php restfull api is working on local xampp apache server. But some post method is not working on online server.

I get my data from db and add to array, after i encode array for print as response. Some method is working and print response.

[Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OL0K.png)

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vseHf.png)

```
    <?php
include "db.php";
include "function.php";
$islem = isset($_GET["islem"]) ? addslashes(trim($_GET["islem"])) : null;
$jsonArray = array();
$jsonArray["hata"] = FALSE; 

$_code = 200;



 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {


    $posta = addslashes($_POST["mail"]);
    $pass = addslashes($_POST["password"]);



    $uyeler = $db->query("SELECT * from users WHERE mail='$posta' AND password='$pass'")->rowCount();

    if(empty($pass) || empty($posta)) {
        $_code = 400; 
        $jsonArray["hata"] = TRUE;
        $jsonArray["hataMesaj"] = "session_failed";
    }else if($uyeler) {
        $data = $db->query("SELECT * from users WHERE mail='$posta' AND password='$pass'");
        $user_data = $data->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $id = $user_data["id"]; 
        $result = $db->query("SELECT * from products")->rowCount();
        if($result){
            $results = $db->query("SELECT * from products ")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $jsonArray["products"] = $results;
            $_code = 200;
        }else {
            $_code = 400;
        $jsonArray["hata"] = TRUE;
        $jsonArray["hataMesaj"] = "not_found_data";
        }
    }else {
        $_code = 400;
        $jsonArray["hata"] = TRUE;
        $jsonArray["hataMesaj"] = "system_error";
    }
}else {
    $_code = 406;
    $jsonArray["hata"] = TRUE;
    $jsonArray["hataMesaj"] = "error";
}


SetHeader($_code);
$jsonArray[$_code] = HttpStatus($_code);
echo json_encode($jsonArray);
?>
```

Comment: Maybe var_dump $_SERVER? See what the request methods are even being seen as

Comment: Trying checking the server's HTTP status code

Comment: I check request method and actually its work when i echo anything